# Problema redirección DNS Hostalia

Tags: dns

Llevo un año utilizando un DNS de hostalia para la redirección de mi VPS. Ayer automáticamente se me renovó el servicio, y dejó de funcionar el DNS. Llevo todo el día intentando arreglarlo, pero no lo consigo.

**Si entro desde www.mipagina.com funciona bien, pero si entro desde mipagina.com, sale una pantalla diciendo "este dominio está reservado".**

La dirección de mi VPS es 85.255.8.178

Esto es lo que tengo en el panel de los DNS de Hostalia
[image: panel dns]

Y aquí la REDIRECCIÓN (desactivada)
[image: redirección]